# How to use Mongoose to populate array of arrays?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
var Stuff = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  expiration: Date,
  cost: Number
});

var Container = new mongoose.Schema({
  stuff: { type: String, ref: 'stuff' },
});

var ContainerWrapper = new mongoose.Schema({
  container: [[container]] // array of arrays
});
```

ContainerWrapper document

```
{
  container: [
    [
      {stuff: 'ID1'},
      {stuff: 'ID2'},
    ],
    [
      {stuff: 'ID3'},
      {stuff: 'ID4'},
      {stuff: 'ID5'},
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I get the population of stuff? I've tried variations of the code below

`ContainerWrapper.find({}).populate({path: 'container.stuff'})`

But none seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some actual data please?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: I have added an answer. This might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a regular populate, you will need a deep-populate. Here is some [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).

```
ContainerWrapperModel
    .find()
    .lean()
    .populate({
        path: 'container',
        model: 'Container', 
        populate: {
            path: 'stuff',
            model: 'Stuff'
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: I will double check, but I do believe I've tried that too, and it did not work.

Comment: @linxtion What is in your "data" when using my solution?

Comment: I get a `{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ stuff: 'SkpTCgxug' }" at path "_id"]`

Comment: If I remove the extra wrapping array, and use `populate('container.stuff')` it works.

Comment: I'm probably just gonna go with using a single array, and manipulate the structure later.

Comment: @linxtion That makes sense because "SkpTCgxug" is not a valid ObjectId. Is there a reason you are using custom id's instead of MongoDB id's? Because if you use the Mongo _id's, everything should work fine.

Comment: I'm currently using `shortid` to generate a url friendly document. I'm surprised it doesn't work with deep populates, but works with `populate('container.stuff')` if the container is 1 level deep.

Comment: So your problem is fixed when using Mongo _id's or if you use only 1 level deep?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example below, should work, if not, comment below

```
ContainerWrapper
    .find({})
    .exec(function(err, data) {

        // get container ids
        // convert [[1, 2],['a', 'b', 'c']] into [1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']
        var containers = data.container.reduce(function(arr, next) {
            next.forEach(function(containerItem) {
                arr.push(containerItem);
            });
            return arr;
        }, []);

        // population options, try playin with other fields
        var options = {path: 'stuff', model: 'Contanier'};

        Container
            .populate(containers, options)
            .exec(function(containerErr, containerData) {

                // populated containers
                console.log(containerData);
            });
    });
```